# How do I include <stdio.h> in jpeglib.h (jpeg-8c)

Tags: c++, eclipse

I want to edit some jpeg files with c++. I linked to libjpg and compiled my code. Compiler complained about typedefs FILE and size_t. I googled the problem and found out that this library is designed to compile under C not C++ so we have to manually add include stdio.h to "jpeglib.h". I did that but this time compiler gave me the folloeing errors:

```
undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress'    JPGImage.cpp    /KFCK/src   line 47 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress'  JPGImage.cpp    /KFCK/src   line 92 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_compress'  JPGImage.cpp    /KFCK/src   line 77 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress'    JPGImage.cpp    /KFCK/src   line 123    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_compress'   JPGImage.cpp    /KFCK/src   line 74 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress' JPGImage.cpp    /KFCK/src   line 120    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header'   JPGImage.cpp    /KFCK/src   line 102    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines'    JPGImage.cpp    /KFCK/src   line 115    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_set_defaults'  JPGImage.cpp    /KFCK/src   line 61 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_set_quality'   JPGImage.cpp    /KFCK/src   line 62 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_start_compress'    JPGImage.cpp    /KFCK/src   line 65 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress'  JPGImage.cpp    /KFCK/src   line 104    C/C++ Problem
```

It can't find the library functions. If I delete the stdio.h line and compile again I get this:

```
‘FILE’ has not been declared    KFCK        line 956, external location: /home/../jpeg-8c/jpeglib.h C/C++ Problem
‘FILE’ has not been declared    KFCK        line 957, external location: /home/../jpeg-8c/jpeglib.h C/C++ Problem
‘size_t’ does not name a type   KFCK        line 756, external location: /home/../jpeg-8c/jpeglib.h C/C++ Problem
‘size_t’ does not name a type   KFCK        line 768, external location: /home/../jpeg-8c/jpeglib.h C/C++ Problem
‘size_t’ has not been declared  KFCK        line 799, external location: /home/../jpeg-
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: `studio.h`? With that amount of attention to detail, it's hard to believe that any particular advice will save you in the long run.

Comment: @KerrekSB `studio.h` is one of those libraries reserved for sexy programmers, we just don't like to mention it to the rest of you lest you think we're bragging.

Comment: I find it cleaner to fix this by a wrapper header: `// jpeglib.hpp #include <stdio.h> extern "C" { #include "jpeglib.h" }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the #include  back. But it looks awfully like you are not adding a -ljpeg or something similar when you are linking. Also you need to make sure that if you are including this in C++ code you may need to do:

```
extern "C" {
#include <jpeglib.h>
}
```

Comment: I came back to accept this answer 10 years later. Did not want to rush it :)