# compiling a c++ program depending on jpeglib.h

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

I'm trying to compile a C++ program (in eclipse) that includes `<jpeglib.h>` which is a c header file. I'm getting this error.

> usr/include/jpeglib.h:790:3: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type
>   size_t free_in_buffer;        /* # of byte spaces remaining in buffer
>   */

Should modify `<jpeglib.h>` to include `<cstddef>` or is there a better way to resolve this?

Comment: Report error to maintainers of jpeglib ?

Comment: "which is a standard c header" - no, it isn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I include <stdio.h> in jpeglib.h (jpeg-8c)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031615/how-do-i-include-stdio-h-in-jpeglib-h-jpeg-8c)

Comment: @JETM not a duplicate that post doesn't answer the question. regards

Comment: Does it suffice if you put the inclusion of cstddef before the one of jpeglib.h in *your* code? Sure, somewhat dirty workaround, but makes the program independent of a correct version of jpeglib.